# Elements position changes when i minimize the window

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

I have a problem with my page. Whenever i minimize the window all the positioning of elements goes off and things get distorted. Please help me. Am using bootstrap elements.

Comment: Please post some code, otherwise how can we know what you mean?

Comment: Consider bootstrap website. http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html. Resize your browser and check the website. The element shrinks when resized to lower width.

Comment: Yes, the page adjust itself to the new width and height. Is that a problem? If so, I'd say remove the media queries.

Comment: Compare the same with www.facebook.com. The elements doesn't adjust to the re sized height and width. Instead it makes use of scroll-bar. I need that feature in my page.

Comment: Like I said, remove the media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix a width/min-width to your principal wrap. I think it will fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you Greg for your answer. I added width and min-width in css of body tag, that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

remove the file "bootstrap-responsive.css" from your css files if you're looking for a more "static" website. You might want to read up on responsive design... having a website that isn't responsive helps to alienate potential mobile users... that's just my two cents.